# Not any listener for ServletConfig

Tags: java, events, servlets

I have one question that while there is a listener for `ServletContext` events why there is none for `ServletConfig` events? Or if it is there kindly tell me what is it?

Comment: Events on the creation of ServletConfig object,its destruction. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the classes you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

ServletContext is sharable throughout all servlet, ServletCofig is belongs to particular servlet. so at the context levet if you want to perform some task before processing any request than listener class has given to perform some opration at context level and you no need to write the code for that.

ServletConfig is belongs to particular servlet so developer has to manage the opration at config level and there is filter where you can configure your filter with particular servlet in web.xml